# input_tensor is not connected to anything in onnx but can still do inference. How?

Tags: deep-neural-networks

I converted an effdet model trained on custom dataset from tensorflow to onnx and tried to further convert it to tensorrt engine file. However, while doing so, I got uint8 issue ([tensorrt does not support it](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/api/python_api/infer/FoundationalTypes/DataType.html)). So, I thought of checking out the onnx file using [netron.app](https://netron.app). I see that the `input_tensor` data type is `uint8` that explains this error but I also see that it is not connected to anything and I can still do inference using this onnx file. As per my understanding, the `input_tensor` should be connected to any other node to perform further calculations. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I can share the onnx file if required.
Any idea what is happening here? Below is a screenshot from the netron app.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a non compliant implementation that assumes the unconnected input tensor to be Connected anyway?